# C++ and Zip Utils

Tags: c++, zip

I'm trying to add zip handling to my project and i've found Zip Utils, described here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7530/Zip-Utils-clean-elegant-simple-C-Win32?msg=4746694#xx4746694xx

So as described there, i add zip.cpp to my project file and include zip.h. But when i try to compile the project it seems like some library is missing even though the autor of Zip Utils says that the only thing to make it working is to do what i've already done. Screen with errors:

http://oi59.tinypic.com/2e3r6ro.jpg

Do you have any ideas what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you include `zip.h`? In Qt Creator (just guessing from image), included header files should be listed in the left column.

Comment: Yes, i'm sure, but as you can see, all the errors are detected in the zip.h file

Comment: after i included windows.h in the zip.h file i got this:
http://oi60.tinypic.com/91i2s6.jpg

Answer (score 2):

*(Moved from comment to question.)* You should `#include <windows.h>` to have `DWORD` type and `DECLARE_HANDLE` macro declared. I find strange that the `zip.h` doesn’t do that.

Functions of the ZIP library don’t take `char*` arguments but `wchar_t*`. You can create a `wchar_t` literal using `L"text"` syntax (http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/69ze775t.aspx).

So this should work:

```
HZIP hz = CreateZip(L"simple1.zip", 0);
// etc.
```

Comment: Ok, i've done that and it seems like it works, but now other errors come in:

http://oi61.tinypic.com/2m4omc2.jpg

Comment: @jogproof You can convert `wchar_t` to `char` array like here: http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/688683-how-convert-wchar_t-char#post2737654 but… are you sure you still want to use such a buggy library?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's so buggy because it works fine for others, even without any of the changes i've made so far. I can't figure out why i do have those troubles.

Answer (score 0):

You included zip.h but probably forgot to add zip.cpp into your project.

1) Copy zip.cpp into your project folder.

2) In the project explorer, right click "Source Files" filter then choose add existing file(s).

3) click the file zip.cpp then click "ok" to include it in your project.